# Outer join does not display wanted (null) rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table which contains User IDs, Period IDs and Qty:

```
User Period Qty
---- ------ ---
   1  11201   3
   1  11202   2
   1  11203   5
   2  11202   4
   2  11203   1
```

Note: User 2 started in Period 11202 so he/she does not have a row for Period 11201

I need to get the Users only from the latest Period...

```
SELECT User FROM table WHERE Period = 11203
```

...and then use these User IDs on the same table to get Period 11201 and 11202 Qty for both users.

The problem: **I need to see the `(null)` Qty for User 2 in Period 11201**. Like so:

```
User Period    Qty
---- ------  -----
   1  11201      3
   1  11202      2
   2  11201 (null)
   2  11202      4
```

I can't figure out the query/joins to achieve it. So far I have this but predictably it gives me only 3 rows (User 1, Periods 11201/11202 and User 2, Period 11202):

```
SELECT a.User, a.Period, a.Qty
FROM (SELECT User FROM table WHERE Period = 11203) b
LEFT JOIN table a
ON b.User = a.User
WHERE a.Period BETWEEN 11201 AND 11202
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get all the required periods and make a Cartesian product of these with the Users first, and then outer join to that:

```
SELECT b.User, p.Period, a.Qty
FROM (SELECT User FROM table WHERE Period = 11203) b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Period FROM table 
            WHERE Period BETWEEN 11201 AND 11202) p
LEFT JOIN table a
ON a.User = b.User
AND a.Period = p.Period
```

Note also the SELECT needs to get the User and Period from the outer table not the inner one, otherwise **everything** will be null on the rows where the user is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Your `where` clause filters out rows where `a.Period` is null.  Move it to the `on` clause:

```
LEFT JOIN table a
ON a.User = b.User
AND a.Period = p.Period
AND a.Period BETWEEN 11201 AND 11202
```

Or explicitly accept `null` values:

```
WHERE a.Period is null OR a.Period BETWEEN 11201 AND 11202
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out all the differences between LEFT/RIGHT and OUTER/INNER joins?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html